# Read values from test yml files

Tags: spring-boot, junit, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have a Spring Boot file with test YAML file `application-test.yml` located under `src/test/resources`:

```yaml
keycloak:
  endpoint: https://test.org
```

Into JUnit test I tried to read the values using:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@PropertySource("classpath:application-test.yml")
public class KeycloakConnectionTest {

    @Value("${keycloak.endpoint}")
    private String ENDPOINT;

    @Test
    void connectionTest() {
        String format = String.format("grant_type=%s&client_id=%s&username=%s", GRANT_TYPE......);
        System.out.println(format);
    }
}
```

When I run the test I get output: `grant_type=null`

Do you know why I get null values?

Answer (score 0):

The annotation `@PropertySource` does not load by default the YAML files as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.yaml.mapping-to-properties) (emphasizes mine):

> YAML files cannot be loaded by using the `@PropertySource` or `@TestPropertySource` annotations. So, in the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use a properties file.

I recommend either overriding `application.yml` in the `src/test/resources` or running the test under the `test` profile in case `application-test.yml` is used as long as Spring Boot [automatically detects](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.profile-specific) the profile-specific configuration.

Comment: Can you show me the complete Java code for JUnit test?

Comment: It must be a `@SpringBootTest` that loads the context.